# How to make a wrapper component in WinUI

Tags: .net, xaml, winui-3

This is what I want to achieve:

MyPage.xaml

```
<Page>
  <MyCustomWrapper>
      <TextBlock>Hello from the page</TextBlock>
  </MyCustomWrapper>
</Page>
```

MyCustomWrapper.xaml

```
<????>
  <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock>Hello from the Wrapper</TextBlock> 
    <INSERT-CHILD-HERE />
  </StackPanel>
</????>
```

Is this possible in WinUI?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom control derived from the `ContentControl`.

**CustomWrapper.cs**

```cs
public class CustomWrapper : ContentControl
{
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<controls:CustomWrapper>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock>Hello from the Wrapper</TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</controls:CustomWrapper>
```